# How to display multiple choice grid from google forms using apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a google form with a multiple choice grid question:

```
Status
           Ok  Bad  Work  Cancel
Category1  *    *    *      *
Category2  *    *    *      *
```

I need to use the apps script to display the values for each category in the work messenger
Where did I go wrong please help

This is my code, I tried to display specific statuses in this way (I am attaching part of the code)

```
`if(payload["Status [Category1]"]) {
  status_cat1 = "Category1: " + payload[Status [Category1]] + " ";
} else {
 status_cat1 = ""
}
if(payload["Status [Category2]"]) {
  status_cat2 = "Category2: " + payload["Status [Category2]"] + " ";
} else {
  status_cat2 = ""
}

var text = status_cat1 + status_cat2`
```

It displays undefined, but I choose the statuses

Comment: I'm not sure what your payload looks like but if its an object shouldn't it be `payload["Status"]["Category 1"]` to access a property of payload?

Comment: That's what I thought too, but this solution doesn't work - it's not the right way to access the status.
Solved the problem differently:
The status is passed in an array, and separated by "," between responses (example: Status=[Ok,Cancel]). To extract the statuses, separated the value before "," and after it. As a result, I got what I needed.